# ¿Se puede usar 'meter' en la pregunta "¿Qué has metido en la sopa?"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vulgaridades

Ayer alguien (cuyo idioma natal es el catalán) me advirtió contra el uso de la palabra *meter* en la pregunta "¿Qué has metido en la sopa?" a causa de sonar un poco vulgar. Me aconsejó que usara *poner* en su lugar. A mi entender, tanto *poner* como *meter* se pueden traducir como *to put* en inglés, pero *poner* significa *'colocar en una superficie'* y *meter* significa *'introducir dentro de'*.

Mi preguntas son:

- ¿Por qué sería el uso de *meter* inadecuado en esta situación?
- ¿Hay zonas en que no tiene está connotación mala?

Comment: mater adentro es pleonasmo  ?

Comment: No he dicho 'meter adentro'

Comment: meter "en" en lugar de meter "a"

Comment: @Mike - OP no dijo *meter a*.  ¿O acaso propones que diga *meter a* en lugar de *meter en*?

Answer (score 2):

*Meter* es más específicamente "introducir", y si le sigue una preposición ésta generalmente será *en* (o *dentro de*), mientras que *poner* es más general. Al menos en mi dialecto (rioplatense) *meter* y *poner* suenan igualmente bien (o mal) en casi todas las situaciones, incluyendo la de tu ejemplo. Si alguien me pregunta *«¿Qué le has metido a la sopa?»* la verdad es que me sonará brusco, quizá descortés, pero sentiría lo mismo si me preguntase *«¿Qué le has puesto a la sopa?»*. El problema está en lo directo de la pregunta y lo que implica, no en el verbo utilizado.

*Meter* puede sonar un poco vulgar en algunos casos, pero cambiarlo por *poner* no soluciona el asunto, porque ambos son verbos muy comunes y poco formales. Para evitar este problema se lo puede reemplazar por otros verbos, como *colocar*, *agregar*, *introducir*, etc. Por ejemplo, en una receta de cocina se puede decir:

> ***Coloque*** un kilogramo de harina en un bol... **Agregue** dos yemas de huevo... **Añada** dos cucharadas de azúcar... **Vuelque** la preparación en un molde metálico... **Introduzca** el molde en el horno...

O bien si es una pregunta como la de tu ejemplo, aunque sea formal, para ser cortés debe hacerse de otra manera, quizá más indirecta, por ejemplo:

> *¿Le has puesto algún condimento especial a la sopa?*
>   *¿Qué es ese sabor diferente que tiene esta sopa?*

Los casos donde suena mal *meter* en vez de *poner* dependen del dialecto, pero desde el principio se usa *meter* para muchas cosas que resultan bruscas o desagradables, como *«meterse en la vida de alguien»* (entrometerse), *«meterse en la conversación»* (interrumpir para hablar uno), *«meter a alguien en un puesto»* (darle un puesto de trabajo a alguien que no lo merece), y frases hechas como *«meter mano, meter cizaña, meter la nariz»*. O sea, el verbo *meter* está muchas veces asociado a cosas malas en el uso habitual. Quizá por eso a alguien le suena mal en otro contexto.

Comment: @aparente001 Expandí el párrafo y añadí unos ejemplos.

Comment: @aparente001 Estoy describiendo cómo se hace para no sonar vulgar o demasiado familiar.

Comment: @aparente001 Hecho.